# to invert a GPIO input

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

This is my Code to start my other Code where i defined my Laser to start.
But in this Code i want to have a Button which starts my other script if i put press it.
But what this code does is it activate my code continuous.
What can i change in it ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
#GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(15,GPIO.IN) #GPIO17

#input = GPIO.input(27)
#print ("input",input)

while True :
    #inputValue = GPIO.input(11)
    #print ("input01",inputValue)
    #time.sleep(1)
    erg= GPIO.wait_for_edge(15,GPIO.RISING, bouncetime=20)
    print ("Input",2)
    #if (GPIO.input(11) == GPIO.HIGH):
    #if erg==15:
    print ("Input",1)
    time.sleep(3)
    #inputValue = 1
    os.system("python /home/pi/gpio.py")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run `os.system('python /home/pi/gpio.py')` you start new process and your main process get back to work on its while loop.

As I understood your idea was to wait until button is pressed and then go to some other state waiting for something new to happen.
You don't need to start new process just import module [(doc)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html). When button was clicked break loop and run code from the imported module.

Also you may find it interesting to replace `wait_for_edge` with `event_detected` method. More about it [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/).